# IntelliSense suggestion with mixed words

Tags: visual-studio-code

In JetBrains editors, I can for example write "tbl" to get "table" on auto completion. As I remember, I could do this in VS Code too but something seems broken or I'm delusional. All I did was install and uninstall Microsoft IntelliCode extension and some themes. Is there any way I can fix this?

GIF: gfycat.com/abandonedultimategreatwhiteshark

Comment: you can define custom Emmet abbreviations, `table` expansion is handles by Emmet

Comment: what is this `GIF` stuff

Comment: thanks, i know i can define custom abbreviations but i'm not talking about a specific abbreviation. in jetbrains, it's not a custom abbreviation but the code auto completion shows it because the letters are included in the word. it works on every single thing so "sct", "sctn", "scin", "scn" brings up "section". in vs code, as soon as i write a different letter, it's gone.

Comment: search or write an extension that does this soft matching of prefixes for html tags, `CompletionItemProvider`